# How can I create an ASP.Net MVC Helper to inspect other inputs on a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I would like to create an extension helper with the following signature:

- public static MvcHtmlString
  BindMissingFor(this HtmlHelper
  htmlHelper, Expression> expression )

I would like this method to reflect through the supplied expression model and look for bind-able properties that have not already been bound on the form.

The use case is I would like to have some Views that only allow the user to interact with a portion of my Model.  But, I would like to persist the entire model between multiple views (a wizard).

My current solution is to use a hidden-input for each field I don't want displayed.  I'll probably do the same thing with this extension method, but I would like it to do the work for me instead of copy/pasting.

Is there a way to inspect the current form for inputs/selects from within an HtmlHelper extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way an html helper to know what happens in other parts of your view such as inspecting other form fields unless you pass it as argument. Also it is not very clear what you mean by *look for bind-able properties that have not already been bound on the form*. For persisting state in a wizard you might take a look at the [Html.Serialize](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/10/08/Leveraging-ASPNET-MVC-2-futures-ViewState.aspx) helper currently situated in the MVC Futures assembly. The idea behind this helper is that it allows you to serialize some model object (marked as `[Serializable]`) as hidden field inside a form and get its value back in a controller action using the `[Deserialize]` attribute. Behind the scenes it uses WebForms ViewState. You can also encrypt it. It is a good way of persisting state on the client between multiple pages.

Comment: Thanks, by "look for bind-able properties" just meant any property that wasn't read-only and wasn't already on the form.